# Set the value of variable to a self-evaluating code

Tags: common-lisp

I've done some tests in Common Lisp :

```
(defvar *a* 0)
(defvar *b* *a*)
(setf *b* 5)
*b* ; returns 5 of course
*a* ; returns 0. Is there a way to set it to 5 without setting *a* directly, via *b* ?
```

Is there **a simple way** to simultaneously :

- set the value of `*b*` as a sort of "function" which checks if the value of `*b*` is a symbol, if "yes" access to the value of the symbol (here `*a*`) and so on until it is a non-symbol atom or a symbol which points to nothing or to himself,
- `*b*` is self-evaluating (important, i do not want to `(funcall ...)` everywhere) and returns the non-symbol atom or ...(see definition above).

The question can be reformulated : Is this possible to set a variable to a function, and when evaluating this variable evaluate the function ? Is there a way to force and control self-evaluation ?

I've thought to change the `eval` function (probably a very bad idea), or to create a custom `defvar` and custom `setf`, but maybe is there a built-in tool for this ?

I know it is possible to set `*b*` to a function like `(lambda () *a*)` but I would prefer to use only `*b*` instead of `(funcall *b*)` for code readability.

Note : I have a preference for a non-macro solution since i could use this feature at runtime.

Comment: Do you want to implement a kind of variable unification?

Comment: @coredump I was just toying with the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`define-symbol-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm):

```
(defvar *a* 1)
(define-symbol-macro *b* *a*)
*b*
==> 1
(setq *b* 5)
*a*
==> 5
```

See also [Symbols as Forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_abaa.htm).

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what i was looking for. :)